# Modeling a One to One Relation with Optional Tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**Context:**
I have a table with a lot of columns. I would like to break this data up because it will be used by people from a frontend like Metabase. The data is for people who will be doing simple queries that the frontend guides them through, so it won't be queried with raw SQL and I'm not worried about performance or complexity of multiple join statements etc. Additionally, I don't want to go through hundreds of columns to create "models" for them on the front end. I have very little database design experience myself and am having some trouble grasping how the following example would be implemented in SQLAlchemy.

A lot of examples are just one `parent` and one `child` and the concept is a bit nebulous in my mind because the docs SQLAlchemy makes it seem like a `one-to-one` relationship is one parent and one child, but my understanding is that its one record in a `parent` table to one record in any `child` table, though I could be very wrong in my understanding.

**Example:**
There are 11 tables and each record in a table only corresponds to a single record in any other table, but some tables depending on a particular column are optional. I want to ensure that when I write and delete records the records on any optional table are removed as well. I'd also like to be able to kind of mix and match any table with any other table by the `table1.id`, where able.

```
Table 1:     Table 2 (for type a):   Table 3 (for type b):
index        index                   index
id           table_1.id              table_1.id
name         some_info               some_info_1
type         other_info              other_info_1
```

Attempt:

```py
# ...
class Contract(Base):
    __tablename__: "contract"
    index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    id = Column(String)
    issue_date = Column(Date)
    rate_type = Column(String)

    # relationship("Rate_type_a", cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True)
    # relationship("Rate_type_b", cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True)
    # Not sure how to setup relationship() and or backrefs
#...

class Rate_type_a(Base):
    # Optional based on contract.type
    __tablename__: "rate_type_a"
    index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    id = Column(String, ForeignKey("contract.id"))
    issue_date = Column(Date)
    rate = Column(Integer)
#...

class Rate_type_b(Base):
    # Optional based on contract.type
    __tablename__: "rate_type_b"
    index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    id = Column(String, ForeignKey("contract.id"))
    issue_date = Column(Date)
    rate = Column(Integer)
    weight = Column(Integer)
# ...

class Other_info(Base):
    # Other Columns that are part of every contract for example
    # ...
```

**Edit:**
It seems I might be able to simplify, this by just putting all rate data in a single table, getting creative with column names, though this is still not ideal as it would have quite a few columns still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pretty much gets me the behavior I expected. Though I don't understand it completely if anyone wants to chime in.

```py
# ...
class Contract(Base):
    __tablename__: "contract"
    index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    id = Column(String, unique=True)
    type = Column(String)

    """
    The relationship with the `Type_a` Class
    `uselist=False` makes it a true one-to-one relation,
    though it seems like it could be left out according to
    the documentation returning only a single record is not 
    enforced.

    Relationships are connected to other relationships, not 
    columns. eg: `back_populates="parent"` in `Type_a`.

    Cascade (cascade="all, delete") ensures that the related 
    records are deleted, this needs to be in the parent and 
    each child.
    """

    type_a = relationship("Type_a", uselist=False, back_populates="parent", cascade="all, delete")
    type_b = relationship("Type_b", uselist=False, back_populates="parent", cascade="all, delete")

class Type_a(Base):
    # Optional based on contract.type
    __tablename__: "type_a"

    """
    It seems like it's not considered good practice to not 
    have a primary key or to use a column that is both a 
    Foreign Key and a Primary Key. But I can't really see the 
    benefit in not doing this in a one-to-one relationship. 
    Clarification would be great.
    """

    # index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    # Cannot use `id` as the variable name because id Exists 
    # in class Contract
    contract_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("contract.id"), primary_key=True)
    rate = Column(Integer)

    # Relationship - Cascade back to parent
    parent = relationship("Contract", back_populates="type_a", cascade="all, delete")

    
#...

class Type_b(Base):
    # Optional based on contract.type
    # index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    # Cascade to delete related records
    contract_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("contract.id"), primary_key=True)
    rate = Column(Integer)
    parent = relationship("Contract", back_populates="type_b", cascade="all, delete")
# ...
```

Add Records:

```py
# ...
    async with async_session() as session:
        # Record 1
        record1 = Contract()
        record1.id = "ADCEGG002300"
        record1.type = "a"

        # Record 1 Rate Table A
        record1_rate = Type_a()
        record1_rate.contract_id = "ADCEGG002300"
        record1_rate.rate = 1000

        # Record 2
        record2 = Contract()
        record2.id = "ADCEGG002400"
        record2.type = "b"

        # Record 2 Rate Table B
        record2_rate = Type_b()
        record2_rate.contract_id = "ADCEGG002400"
        record2_rate.rate = 2000
       
       session.add(record1)
       session.add(record2)
       session.add(record1_rate)
       session.add(record1_rate)
       await session.commit()

#...
```

Delete Record:

```py
#...
        # From Type_b
        contract = await session.execute(select(Type_b).where(Type_b.contract_id == "ADCEGG002400"))

        # From Contract Table
        # contract = await session.execute(select(Contract).where(Contract.id == "ADCEGG002400"))
        await session.delete(contract.scalar())
        await session.commit()
#...
```